# "Hold position" command

Tags: rome-2-total-war

Has anyone found a way to tell your troops to hold their position? For the life of me I cannot find a way to set my troops defensive, so they won't pursue at will.

I have a wonderful setup at the end of a bridge that I can defend, but my troops always wind up chasing the enemy across the bridge.

Comment: Odd, my troops never engage the enemy unless I tell them to or they're being attacked (missile troops do shoot at the enemy when in *Fire at will* mode or run away when in *Skirmish* mode)

Comment: They standby until the enemy engages them. Once that happens and the enemy pulls back, my men chase.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this forum post](http://forums.totalwar.com/showthread.php/94255-Battle-and-Unit-teams-What-we-are-working-on) by a Creative Assembly employee, units now behave as if they were in guard mode by default (which is why the button was removed), and should not actually chase anything unless you have explicitly ordered them to attack a unit (in which case following a unit that is running away seems like the correct behavior). However, there seem to be bugs involved where units sometimes chase units that they aren't supposed to chase:

> A number of people have expressed disappointment that we have removed the Guard Mode button. In fact (as many have realised), guard mode behaviour has not been removed – it is now an inherent property of units: they have guard mode behaviour by default. If you want units to chase down routers & retreaters, you have to order them to do so. However, some unintended pursuit actions are occurring and will be fixed in upcoming patches.